# How to get exact count of value from json

Tags: javascript

I have a json data like this. I want the exact count of "pass" value in my json.

```
[{
    "Status1" : "pass",
    "Status2" : "Fail",
    "Status3" : "Ready"
},{
    "Status1" : "Fail",
    "Status2" : "pass",
    "Status3" : "Ready"
},{
    "Status1" : "pass",
    "Status2" : "Fail",
    "Status3" : "pass"
},{
    "Status1" : "pass",
    "Status2" : "Fail",
    "Status3" : "Ready"
}]
```

Here is what I am trying getting fail.

```
var count = 0;
for(var pass in json)
    if(json.hasOwnProperty(pass))
        count++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close:

```
var count = 0;
for(var obj of json)
  count += Object.values(obj).filter(k => k === "pass").length;
```

You need to iterate over all objects in the json array, then filter their values to contain only "pass", count them (via .length) and sum them up (+=).

If you dont want to get the total " pass" count, but the number of objects containing a pass value its even more easy:

```
var count = 0;
for(var obj of json)
  if(Object.values(obj).includes("pass")) count++;
```

---

The whole thing in ES5:

```
var count = 0;
for(var key in json)
  if(Object.keys(json[key]).filter(function(sub){return json[key][sub] === "pass";}).length) count++;
```

Comment: This code is breaking in IE. Any workaround for that

Comment: @david if you want to support you should ask for an *ES5* answer. Edited...

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was not aware with ES5 concept. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can filter objects by whether it contains any property with value "pass". Something like this:

```js
const data = [{
  "Status1" : "pass",
  "Status2" : "Fail",
  "Status3" : "Ready"
},{
  "Status1" : "Fail",
  "Status2" : "pass",
  "Status3" : "Ready"
},{
  "Status1" : "pass",
  "Status2" : "Fail",
  "Status3" : "pass"
},{
  "Status1" : "pass",
  "Status2" : "Fail",
  "Status3" : "Ready"
}]

const count = data.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(key => {
  return obj[key] === 'pass'
})).length

console.log(count)
```

Useful methods:

- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Array.prototype.filter](http://Array.prototype.filter())
- [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
  "Status1" : "pass",
  "Status2" : "Fail",
  "Status3" : "Ready"
},{
  "Status1" : "Fail",
  "Status2" : "pass",
  "Status3" : "Ready"
},{
  "Status1" : "pass",
  "Status2" : "Fail",
  "Status3" : "pass"
},{
  "Status1" : "pass",
  "Status2" : "Fail",
  "Status3" : "Ready"
}]

console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
```